# Navbarcontrol auto Expand by MouseHover or MouseEnter event in Devexpress

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a problem with Devexpress 13.1.8 in Winform is: When the cursor is located on NavbarGroup I want to NavbarGroup auto Expand. I think i must catch event of Mouse, but I don't know how. 
So, how can I do that? 
Sorry, my English's not good. 
Thanks all of you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should start from reading the documentation: [Obtain Hit Information](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1702).

The example provided with the [How to: Get the Group That Is Hovered Over](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument4893) help-article is demonstrated the approach which should be suitable for you:
using DevExpress.XtraNavBar;

```
void navBarControl1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
   NavBarHitInfo hitInfo = navBarControl1.CalcHitInfo(e.Location);
   if (hitInfo.InGroup) {
      NavBarGroup group = hitInfo.Group;
      // perform operations on the group here
      //...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should go through [Expand and Collapse Groups](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument1696) and then you require to get that NavBarGroup is hovered or not. You can check this on the handler for the MouseMove event as described in the [DevExpress example How to: Get the Group That Is Hovered Over](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument4893) as already suggest by @DmitryG.

```
void navBarControl1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
   NavBarHitInfo hitInfo = navBarControl1.CalcHitInfo(e.Location);
   if (hitInfo.InGroup) {
      NavBarGroup group = hitInfo.Group;
      // perform operations on the group here
      group.Expanded = true;  //Expand then group or you custom logic
   }
}
```

**References:**
[Which event to use when collapsing/expanding the groups in the NavBar's Explorer views?](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A677)
[How to expand NavBar groups by clicking their captions](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A2726)
[XtraNavBar expand one group only](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/CQ63738)